# Search Nearby Places in Android Studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, kotlin, google-nearby

I want to search for nearby places (ex: hospitals, schools, general clinics, etc.) in a certain radius of the user's current location.
I have successfully managed to get the users current location, but don't know how to look for nearby places in the radius.
I have managed to set up the html-attributions to get the nearby places, which looks like the following:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${location.latitude},${location.longitude}&radius=1500&type=restaurant&key=YOUR_API_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$%7Blocation.latitude%7D,$%7Blocation.longitude%7D&radius=1500&type=restaurant&key=YOUR_API_KEY) *(I have put my key)*

But I don't seem to know where and how do I implement this Url. Only if someone could tell me how could I use this URL. That too could be of great help!
Thank You!

This is my code currently:

````
package com.sampathpatro.vipalsiddh

import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Address
import android.location.Geocoder
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import java.io.IOException

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

 private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
 private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
 private lateinit var lastLocation: Location

private fun placeMarkerOnMap(location: LatLng){
     val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(location)
     val titleString = getAddress(location)
     markerOptions.title(titleString)
     map.addMarker(markerOptions)
 }

 private fun getAddress(latLng: LatLng): String {
     val geocoder = Geocoder (this)
     val addresses: List<Address>
     val address: Address?
     var addressText = ""

     try {
         addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1)

         if (null != addresses && addresses.isNotEmpty()){
             address = addresses[0]
             for (i in 0 until address.maxAddressLineIndex){
                 addressText += if (i==0) address.getAddressLine(i) else
                     "\n" + address.getAddressLine(i)
             }
         }
     } catch (e: IOException){
         Log.e("MapsActivity", e.localizedMessage)
     }
     return  addressText
 }

 companion object {
     private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
 }

 private fun setUpMap() {
     if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
             PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
         LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
         return
     }

     map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
     fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->
         if (location != null){
             lastLocation = location
             val currentLatLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
             placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLng)
             map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 12f))
         }
     }
 }

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
     // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
     val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
         .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
     mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

     fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

 }

 /**
  * Manipulates the map once available.
  * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
  * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
  * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
  * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
  * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
  * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
  */
 override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
     map = googleMap

     map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
     map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
     setUpMap()
 }

 override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?) = false
} ```
````

Comment: Google Maps' - [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/overview) is exactly Places API but designed for Android where you don't need to use HTTP requests but instead methods from the SDK itself. For example, Current Place will help you to find the local business or other place where the device is currently located. To get you started, you can check this link: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OkHttp library to safely make API calls.
include the library in your gradle file

Use `GSON` library with it and it will make this easy for you , for simplicity i will simply get it to work by `JSONObject`

in the module level gradle, include this

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.1")
```

Use this method to make calls

```
fun makeApiCall(location:Location){
    val request = Request.Builder().url("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${location.latitude},${location.longitude}&radius=1500&type=restaurant&key=YOUR_API_KEY")
                 .build()

    val response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute().body().string()
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(response) // This will make the json below as an object for you

    // You can access all the attributes , nested ones using JSONArray and JSONObject here


}
```

When you make a api call , you get something like this as a response

```
            {
                "debug_log" : {
                "line" : []
                },
                "html_attributions" : [],
                "logging_info" : {
                "experiment_id" : [],
                "query_geographic_location" : "AU"
                },
                "results" : [
                {
                    "geometry" : {
                        "location" : {
                            "lat" : -33.86879,
                            "lng" : 151.194217
                        }
                    },
                    "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
                    "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
                    "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
                    "opening_hours" : {
                        "open_now" : false,
                        "weekday_text" : []
                    },
                    "photos" : [
                        {
                            "height" : 426,
                            "html_attributions" : [
                            "\u003ca href=\"https://www.google.com/maps/views/profile/104066891898402903288\"\u003eRhythmboat Cruises\u003c/a\u003e"
                            ],
                            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAA-YL_I_Gk02blOX6S0nKHry8PFu9pDyp3Y9AnqISsa3Eq8mkbdD5mXuu1Fax60s0nSy3iiX-h5j-ztyLHcc1-782MsLQsgLLa4t3ZgDmCMll-a8ABapZGnZwDKByk67LFEhBgedv_u_eYFsEo9ay8jxJjGhTUHKPJ4G82vBJqSNliuv7UlAtclw",
                            "width" : 640
                        }
                    ],
                    "place_id" : "ChIJyWEHuEmuEmsRm9hTkapTCrk",
                    "reference" : "CnRmAAAAvQlMKw-XtxEY4vWFCvudF7CEMQGI5ycNbfVgGl9rAF75fdiPOiLJw1k9NL2v8ZIJsOJuRS3Lm9Dw1vga4ajycAs7PlxN1MVnnYT9la0pBvEvSQNlyvszKANS1R4P7Mvk_jhqswMggqCUtwJ13LN2hRIQOiAkLTWUi3DOjVVOw7J5IRoUb_cJyJaJNqKdmkDM2f0OjQjh9F0",
                    "scope" : "GOOGLE",
                    "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
                    "vicinity" : "Pyrmont Bay Wharf (Near Australia Maritime Museum), Pyrmont, NSW 2009"
                },
                {
                    "geometry" : {
                        "location" : {
                            "lat" : -33.867591,
                            "lng" : 151.201196
                        }
                    },
                    "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
                    "id" : "a97f9fb468bcd26b68a23072a55af82d4b325e0d",
                    "name" : "Australian Cruise Group",
                    "opening_hours" : {
                        "open_now" : false,
                        "weekday_text" : []
                    },
                    "photos" : [
                        {
                            "height" : 1331,
                            "html_attributions" : [
                            "\u003ca href=\"https://www.google.com/maps/views/profile/110751364053842618118\"\u003eAustralian Cruise Group\u003c/a\u003e"
                            ],
                            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAtEoj29FJcNBccrsu6bHt0xgwVGhYlciCY1fe6gTr_d5_KkeP3LITnOwnpNRJWnX39B04-aIBOKXKJH6ltx948T5vWIYBoah1yZDXsWngWZ5kMsK7xyCB5P_q_xBIBxxUEhAYWeB4PiOm_Jy093fB-j0iGhSYmIs9xB2aa6u-RH8V8lZEk-Q5ig",
                            "width" : 2000
                        }
                    ],
                    "place_id" : "ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0",
                    "reference" : "CnRqAAAAFbukrZvRNsc05TreHUCrPEya5NcN9v0fFLLaK-D1fSyxFTuQlUDhDstU3qwXKw_fADX4W6guUkexax1nufgiYIuGCKoZPEnup1r-LhGGNz9dn1uf9Of5iOtZ1XgCeDjJaYvGbSB3C0pAXL8r9kOsmhIQbx2Sia2DAWTjtSZwuh5aehoUhM6upqBCDLhGruZAGGsCOwAiIq8",
                    "scope" : "GOOGLE",
                    "types" : [
                        "restaurant",
                        "travel_agency",
                        "food",
                        "point_of_interest",
                        "establishment"
                    ],
                    "vicinity" : "32 The Promenade, King Street Wharf 5, Sydney"
                },
                {
                    "geometry" : {
                        "location" : {
                            "lat" : -33.870943,
                            "lng" : 151.190311
                        }
                    },
                    "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
                    "id" : "e644f7f34cf875b9919c6548f1b721947362850a",
                    "name" : "Lunch Cruise with Jazz on Sydney Harbour",
                    "opening_hours" : {
                        "open_now" : false,
                        "weekday_text" : []
                    },
                    "photos" : [
                        {
                            "height" : 292,
                            "html_attributions" : [
                            "\u003ca href=\"https://www.google.com/maps/views/profile/105423912060796272053\"\u003eFrom a Google User\u003c/a\u003e"
                            ],
                            "photo_reference" : "CmRdAAAAR4bqFTKYWdBwZwdBdON_JRD7V_joTwwIPwRUpZIZWkSSd8GQ3P2O-_aQbUJdL2RhoAyzCUIF0f--DI4oXFneTpj5zZfFq-iFiT7i_x0tjnDveIY8tJv-6o0uWSSjYqabEhCKqQWZqrKAoddjDcc64N48GhQZ2T1_ntPzNKCooHpZzlYQ7AxFOA",
                            "width" : 438
                        }
                    ],
                    "place_id" : "ChIJLfySpTOuEmsRPCRKrzl8ZEY",
                    "reference" : "CoQBewAAAFd2fO_YWGTiT4RzXWb5tsOuOt7YyV_ScQOwm0tqJSrAyACCczeOzV-P_mgZLro1oKP_34Nt0nVC_1OEKAQUcd7cUm7xmAMSX-EkbSWiD0kOWGgGgKuDRtb0t_8qsxBGU_izugWCyK7SRWezTxELYNdkS0OEiSWPnvhxvXuQktBBEhAAtEe7fagW2kUR14T1QpVsGhQBO7YpIyYSPvo4zUJuL_bX30nJZw",
                    "scope" : "GOOGLE",
                    "types" : [ "bar", "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
                    "vicinity" : "37 Bank St, Pyrmont"
                    }
                ],
                    "status" : "OK"
            }
```